# Not able to send mail from node mailer and not receiving any error in nodes

Tags: node.js, node-modules, nodemailer

I am trying to send otp generated to users using node mailer but not able to do so, below is the code and the steps followed :

1. Changed the password recommended by google for third party apps.
2. According to the logs the console.log('reached here') is being displayed but the node mailer is not firing and no error logs is being shown.

if someone can please help me resolve this issue.

node.js

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "Gmail",  //smtp.gmail.com 
    port : 465,
    secure: true,
    logger: true,
                debug: true,
                secureConnection: false,
                ignoreTLS: true,
    auth: {
        user: "username@gmail.com",
        pass: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx" //the 16 digit password is inserted here
    },
});

transporter.verify((err, success) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    console.log('Your config is correct');
});

---------------------------------------------------
router.post('/sendEmailOTP', async (req,res) => {
  console.log('checking the email verification:',req.body);
  const otp = generateOTP();

  if (!req.body.email) {
    return res.status(404).send({ message: "Missing Email." });
 }
 try{
    
    console.log('reached here'); // reaching till here successfully.
    
    transporter.sendMail({
      to: req.body.email,
      subject: 'Verify Account',
    html: `
   <div
     class="container"
     style="max-width: 90%; margin: auto; padding-top: 20px"
   >
     <h2>Welcome to the club.</h2>
     <h4>You are officially In ✔</h4>
     <p style="margin-bottom: 30px;">Pleas enter the sign up OTP to get started</p>
     <h1 style="font-size: 40px; letter-spacing: 2px; text-align:center;">${otpGenerated}</h1>
</div>
 `
    },function(err){
      if(err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    })

}catch (e) {

}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code locally and it worked perfectly when I changed the `${otpGenerated}` to `otp` in your html code.